# How can I make my "dash" push me forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to programming and was wondering how I could make my "dash" make me move forward. I watched an online tutorial on how to make a dash work but after trying, the dash would only push me at all if I had written `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * dashSpeed;`. Currently, when I press the dash key, my character's gravity slows down for a second but no movement is made. Can I please get some help in making it push my character?

If you need clarification, please ask!

PS: Sorry for the long script, all my player control is in here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Movement
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public float dashSpeed;
    public float startDashTime;


    public Animator animator;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveInput;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    public float jumpTime;
    private bool isJumping;
    private float dashTime;
    private int direction;
    void Start()
    {
        animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        dashTime = startDashTime;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        // Moving
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);


        }
        else if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
        // Jumping
        if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("IsJumping");
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == true)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
      
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                isJumping = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            

            isJumping = false;
        }
        if (isGrounded == false)
        {

            animator.SetBool("Grounded", false);
            
        }
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Grounded", true);
        }
        // Dashing

        if(direction == 0)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y  == 180))
                    {
                    Dashleft();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    DashRight();
                }
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(dashTime <= 0)
            {
                direction = 0;
                dashTime = startDashTime;
                
            }
            else
            {
                dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;

          
            }
        }
    }
    void Dashleft()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
    }
    void DashRight()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your horizontal velocity is being controlled in `FixedUpdate()`
It is being overriden in every physics frame, so when you change velocity in `DashLeft()` or `DashRight()` methods, velocity is being reset in this line `rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);`
You can do something like this:

```
if (dashTime <= 0)
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
```

So you control your velocity by Input only if player is not dashing